# mongoose looking for a better way to get documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Consider there are 3 collections:**

```
Company: {
    name
}

Department: {
    name,
    company_id
}

Person: {
    name,
    department_id
}
```

and we want to get all persons in a company, by `company name`

I know the way to first get the `company ID` in one query, then get the list of `department_ids` in another query, and then get the list of persons, in another query with the list of Ids:

```js
async function query(){
   let companyId = await Company.findOne({name}).distinct('_id').exec();
   let departmentIds = await Department.find({company_id : companyId } ).distinct('_id').exec();
   let persons = await Person.find({department_id : departmentIds}).exec();
}
```

I want to know if is there any better way to do this, I mean is it possible to use the populate method or aggregation here? and if yes how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use `aggregate` from the `Company` document. Then one more aggregation with lookup to reach the `Company` document.

After reaching the `Company Document`, you can easily match the name value:

```
return await Company.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "departments",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "company_id",
      as: "PersonCompanyTable",
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$PersonCompanyTable'
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'persons',
      localField: 'PersonCompanyTable._id',
      foreignField: 'department_id',
      as: 'PersonsTable'
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      name: name
    }
  }
])
```

I hope, it is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, but I didnt get any result, so i went to chech each stage result, and the first stage, didnt have any result. the "PersonDepartmentTable" is an empty array.

Comment: Hmm. Okay. Sorry for wrong answer friend. If you can't find solution you wish, you may try my answer which is I edited again now. I hope it works fine.

Comment: thank you. I think , i think i use the previous code wrong, now it works. thank you. just need some modification : We should aggregate on "Person" , also in the lookup field : from : "Department" , localField : "department_id" , foreignField : "_id" , as : "PersonDepartment" } .

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just thought as your field's name "departments". But if it's work as you wished at finally, well done. So the previous answer was true and good for you ? According to your answer, i will edit my asnwer again :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways this could be done.  Here's one way to get all persons working for every company using a `"$lookup"` nested inside another `"$lookup"`.

```js
db.Company.aggregate([
  { // get all company departments
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Department",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "company_id",
      "as": "departments",
      "pipeline": [
        { // get all persons in department
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "Person",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "department_id",
            "as": "persons"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "name": 1,
      "persons": {
        // concat all department persons
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$departments",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this.persons"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9usqdCvp4Gv).